# Custom select (dropdown) don't focusing on first element when active

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a custom dropdown and want to make good keyboard support. How do I get focus on my first LI when the UL visible. Didn't find answer by my self.

I take code from there https://codepen.io/beforesemicolon/pen/abNpjKo
On CodePen focus on first element works. But on my page - no... please, tell me if you know :)

Here is the code:

```
function DropDown(dropDown) {
  const [toggler, menu] = dropDown.children;
  
  const handleClickOut = e => {
    if(!dropDown) {
      return document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOut);
    }
    
    if(!dropDown.contains(e.target)) {
      this.toggle(false);
    }
  };
  
  const setValue = (item) => {
    const val = item.textContent;
    toggler.textContent = val;
    this.value = val;
    this.toggle(false);
    dropDown.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    toggler.focus();
  }
  
  const handleItemKeyDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.keyCode === 38 && e.target.previousElementSibling) { // up
      e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
      e.target.previousElementSibling.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
      e.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 40 && e.target.nextElementSibling) { // down
      e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
      e.target.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
      e.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 27) { // escape key
      this.toggle(false);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) { // enter or spacebar key
      setValue(e.target);
    }
  }

  const handleToggleKeyPress = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.keyCode === 27) { // escape key
      this.toggle(false);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) { // enter or spacebar key
      this.toggle(true);
    } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 9) { // tab + shift key
      this.toggle(false);
      document.getElementById("message_email").focus(); 
    } else if (e.keyCode === 9 ) { // tab key
      this.toggle(false);
      document.getElementById("message_text").focus(); 
    } 
  }
  
  toggler.addEventListener('keydown', handleToggleKeyPress);
  toggler.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggle());
  [...menu.children].forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('keydown', handleItemKeyDown);
    item.addEventListener('click', () => setValue(item));
  });
  
  this.element = dropDown;
  this.value = toggler.textContent;

  this.toggle = (expand = null) => {
    expand = expand === null ? menu.getAttribute("aria-expanded") !== "true" : expand;

    menu.setAttribute("aria-expanded", expand);
    
    if(expand) {
      menu.children[0].focus();
      toggler.classList.add('active');
      menu.children[0].focus();
      document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOut);
      dropDown.dispatchEvent(new Event('opened'));
      //toggler.blur();
      
    } else {
      toggler.classList.remove('active');
      toggler.focus();
      dropDown.dispatchEvent(new Event('closed'));
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOut);
    }
  }
}

const dropDown = new DropDown(document.querySelector('.message__dropdown'));
```

Comment: Does a javascript error appear in browsers console?

Comment: No errors appear in browser console

Comment: I think it something about how browser is working... I working in Chrome, but also tested it in Opera and Safari... may they all do something with focus and ignore JS. Because in the code it's very clear written menu.children[0].focus();

Answer (score 0):

Heh... problem was in CSS. Property `{transition-duration}` was written by me for UL (I mean for changing background color, but I didn't choose `{transition-property}`).
After I remove {transition-duration} focusing is working well. Oh my God... it tooks fore hours